# Scrolling output with ccze

Tags: terminal, colors

I love the default fancy output of ccze, but I can't seem to get it scroll property. Executing

```
tail -f something.log | ccze
```

from an X terminal works, but I can't scroll back once the screen has been filled (shift+pgup doesn't do anything).

How can I get it to work as expected?

Comment: as far as I can see, that is not possible with ccze. With multitail it is, although its colouring capabilities are not comparable to ccze/colorize.

Comment: it makes me think then how people actually use this think.. or what for.. :(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ccze` uses the `curses` output mode by default. `(n)curses` is a screen drawing library typically used by fullscreen applications. It switches to the terminal emulator's so-called "alternate screen" which does not have a scrollbar buffer, and the contents of the other, "normal screen" is restored upon exit.

Instead of this, you should use its `ansi` output format which is enabled by any of the `-A`, `--raw-ansi`, `-m ansi` or `--mode=ansi` command line options.

Answer (score 2):

I use `ccze` with `less` to scroll into logs:

```
ccze -A /var/log/logstash/logstash-plain.log | less -R
```

Comment: A '<' is need after '-A'